# Vim, WSL and syntax highlighting

Tags: python-3.x, vim, syntax-highlighting, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opensuse

I've tried to write a python script on OpenSuSE running as WSL on Windows 10. I've got my `.vimrc` that has been working both on Mac and OpenSuSE, but now a few things are broken:

- no syntax highlighting
- no automatic indentation, i.e. when I type `def foo(): <ENTER>`, the indentation remains at position 0.

Setting as some have suggested

```
set term=screen-256color
set t_ut=
```

didn't help.

The rest seems to work: YCM shows suggestions, relative line numbers are displayed, etc.

I've tried to move both `.vimrc` and `.vim`, and then just `:set syntax`. Vim recognizes it as Python showing `syntax=python`, but this is it. So, it seems to be irrelevant to my `.vimrc`.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be fixed?

**EDIT:**

```
:filetype 
filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON

:verbose set ft? 
filetype=python

:scriptnames  

  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
```

Comment: Does `:filetype` show all options are "ON"? Does `:verbose set ft?` show it's set to `filetype=python` as expected? Does `:scriptnames` show that Vim is sourcing files named `syntax/python.vim` and `indent/python.vim` from the Vim runtime directory? Please [edit] your question to include your answers.

Comment: Does your system have files `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/python.vim` and `/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/python.vim` ? Those should have been loaded when you open a file of type `python`, but `:scriptnames` isn't showing them...

Comment: @filbranden : no, and I'm wondering why they were not included. OK, thanks, I've downloaded python.vim and now syntax highlighting works. Lesson learned. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Turned it into an answer. Take a look at whether your SuSE has an RPM for those, installing from SuSE is probably the best option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your Vim install was incomplete, since it was missing files `syntax/python.vim` and `indent/python.vim` under `/usr/share/vim/vim80`, which should have been loaded when editing a file of type Python.

It's possible that OpenSuSE ships the complete Vim runtimes in a separate RPM and for some reason you didn't have it installed?

Ensuring those files are present should fix the issue you're having with syntax and indentation of Python files.

Comment: It's not quite original OpenSuSE, it's WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) version of OpenSuSE. On 'normal' OpenSuSE everything worked as expected – this is what have puzzled me in the first place. And no, I do not see, at least immediately, any extra RPM that would fit the bill.

Answer (score 3):

The missing package is `vim-data`.
So,

```
sudo zypper in vim-data
```

Comment: Since the question was asked about openSUSE:
`sudo zypper in vim-data`